# Refit me showing an error when initializing

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, refit

I am trying to consume a service using Refit and I have the following problem. I was looking at the documentation but I can't find a solution and I don't know if I should do anything else.

**This is my model**

```
public partial class Global
{
    [JsonProperty("updated")]
    public long Updated { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("countryInfo")]
    public List<CountryInfo> CountryInfo { get; set; }
}
```

My second class:

```
public partial class CountryInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("_id")]
    public long? Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("iso2")]
    public string Iso2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("iso3")]
    public string Iso3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lat")]
    public double Lat { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("long")]
    public double Long { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("flag")]
    public Uri Flag { get; set; }
}
```

Application with Refit

```
    Link : https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries
    [Get("/v2/countries")]
    Task<CountryInfo> GetCountry();
```

In my viewModel

```
private async Task GetTaskInterf()
{
    var webApp = RestService.For<ICovidInterface>("https://corona.lmao.ninja");
    var  result = await webApp.GetGlobalCountry();
}
```

At the time of initialization

[image: Result]

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images!

Comment: and there are dozens of existing questions about this specific error - your JSON is an array and you are trying to load it into a single object